# AWS EC2 scp from private subnet instance to bastion

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am using a jump server (bastion) to connect to a private ec2 instance. The connection is successful, however I am not able to scp a jar file from private ec2 instance to the jump server location.

Command:
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XX-XX-X3 ~]$ scp x.jar ec2-user@XX.XXX                                       .XX.XX5:/home/user

Result:
I get "ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XX.XX5 port 22: Connection timed out

Would highly appreciate your input/suggestions to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your security group rules allow traffic to the bastion from the private instance, or is it just from the bastion to the private? I assume from your description you're copying from private to bastion? If your rules are one way have you tried running the reverse scp. So: Scp ec2-user@ip-xxx:/path/to/file.jar ./file.jar

Answer (score 1):

pls try reverse SCP . here 10.169.1.59 is my destination server where ec2 folder reside in my home directory. i am running this command from my bastion server which has ip 10.169.4.173

scp -i tusharc.pem -r 10.169.1.59:/home/tchatterjee/ec2 .

Comment: mind  the dot in last that mean your current working directory in bastion .which was my home dir in bastion.